# Prevent Logging Mapped Exceptions in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, log4j, slf4j

Using Struts 2 I am mapping exceptions for an action (successfully) using 'exception-mapping' but would like to prevent Struts from logging the mapped exception to my error log.

I have tried passing `<param name="exception.logEnabled">false</param>` to the exception mapping and have also tried setting the log level for the specific exception to fatal in my `logback.xml` with no success.

I would prefer not writing a custom implementation of the `ExceptionMappingInterceptor`.

**EDIT:**

For example, I may have an exception `DuplicateIdException` and 2 actions `createPOJO.action` and `updatePOJO.action`. I would like a stack trace to print to the log for the `updatePOJO.action` and NOT for the `createPOJO.action`.

Comment: *I would like each struts action to have a different mapping for DuplicateIdException.* - What stops you? Exception mapping can be per action so as interceptor stack.

Comment: Apologies...I got two of my questions mixed up and have edited this question to reflect that.

Comment: You can conf interceptor stack per action.

Answer (score 0):

This parameter should be set to the interceptor stack

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
   <param name="exception.logEnabled">false</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Setting it to to the exception mapping is wrong, there's no way to use `param` tag with the `exception-mapping` element in the xml configuration.
Also note:

> Global exception mappings are designed to be used with exceptions
>   thrown by action methods (like `execute`). exceptions thrown from
>   constructors will ***not*** be handled by global exception mappings.

Comment: Won't this disable logging for everything under that interceptor?

Comment: Not everything, but for exceptions mapped via global exception mappings.

Comment: I want to disable logging for only the exceptions I have defined mappings for.